# How can i make full width responsive div section using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make the yellow section fullwidth? I tried section and div container fluid within bootstrap and no luck. I think there are fixed dimensions in the parent css that I can’t override. I just want to make a responsive div section fullwidth so I can use a background color or image background. Thanks in advance.

Page in question:
http://dev.dragonscaletech.com/our-story/

```
<div class="container" style="background-color: yellow;">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12 text-center">
  <h2>Reaching the Root of the problem..</h2>
  <h4>Scrubbing your back daily has always been so uncomfortable & 
 unrealistic, until now!</h4>
  <p>The fact that it allowed easy & hands-free access to the absolute hardest to reach area of the human body, meant that we needed to make it count & go after the root of the problem.</p>
  <p>We constantly neglect our back when we shower.</p>
  <p>Every other solution to this widespread hygiene shortcoming requires a full range of arm & body mobility, which frankly, not everyone has.</p>
  <p>Something as common as having sore muscles from last night's work out or even having too much muscle, can limit you from using any of these "alternatives-on-a-stick". Age, injury & disability can make it impossible.</p>
  <p>Once we understood the core issue, we got to work.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome! Most people do not want to click on a link to hunt down your code. Please update your question and include code samples with the issue in question.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap container does have `15px padding` and `row` have `- 15px  margin`. So either add class `row` to your  `section` or give `- 15px margin` to your yellow  `section`.  Hope that will work or try question with code next time for quick response.

Comment: I am wanting the yellow section to be fullwidth on the screen. There is a fixed dimension in the template and I can't figure out to override it. If I remove the padding or margin it doesn't make it yellow across the screen. The change is very minor.

Comment: Did you used `container-fluid`.

Comment: I tried container-fluid with no change. The wordpress theme is affected by @media (min-width: 1200px) . If I change width to 100% is almost stretches fullwidth, but affects every container on the page. I want to make this single container full width. I just tried an ID in css and still no luck.

Comment: It looks like your yellow `container` is enclosed by a bootstrap `container`. check it.

Answer (score 1):

Found this code after a ton of searching on google. Fixed my issue.

```
.row-full{
 width: 100vw;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: -50vw;
 height: 100px;
 margin-top: 100px;
 left: 50%;
 }
```

https://coderwall.com/p/hkgamw/creating-full-width-100-container-inside-fixed-width-container